# Is there a easy way to get dojo/dijit toolkit working with knockout observables?

Tags: html, data-binding, dojo, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

If I have a declared select

```
<select id="sel1" dojoType="dijit.form.Select" >...
```

And I add my knockout data binding

```
<select id="sel1" dojoType="dijit.form.Select" data-bind=".....">...
```

If the knockout array/bind is initialised prior to the dojo.ready they the select box is populated with the correct values, however because dojo re-writes the templates we lose our observables.

I'd rather not migrate to dojo observables but this seems like I'd have to in this case.

I am continuing to investigate but it looks like we'll need to make this move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This is not the answer, although it is a starting point.

---

It looks like there is knockout dojo connector.

https://github.com/imankulov/knockout-dojo-connector/blob/master/sample.html

---

But no samples for observablearrays and binding with selects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of the approach by knockout-dojo-connector. I think a cleaner approach would be to keep your KO bindings in your markup and apply an attr binding for your dojo type.
Something like this should work:
`<select id="sel1" data-bind="attr: {'dojoType': dojoTypeInViewModel}">...`